# How do I fix undefined method `merge!' for "a-sample-blog-post":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec-rails

I have a admin namespaced controller for a simple blog I am writing, as soon as I add in some user support to my test I get back an error, this error only happens when I add the let(:user) { ... } and before { ... } bit

```
 Failure/Error: post :create, :post => blog_post
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `merge!' for "a-sample-blog-post":String
 # ./app/controllers/admin/posts_controller.rb:13:in `create'
 # ./spec/controllers/admin/post_controller_spec.rb:13:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/controllers/admin/post_controller_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

This is on line 13 of PostsController:

```
@post = Post.new(params[:post].merge!(:user => current_user))
```

My simple test code is as follows

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Admin::PostsController do
  describe "new blog post with valid attributes" do

    let(:blog_post) { Factory(:post) }
    let(:user) { Factory(:user, :admin => true) }

    before { sign_in user }

    it "should be valid" do
      lambda do 
        post :create, :post => blog_post
      end.should change(Post, :count).by(1)
    end
  end
end
```

And in case this helps, here is my factories.rb file

```
Factory.define :post do |post|
  post.title          "A sample blog post"
  post.content        "Duis mollis, est non commodo eget lacinia odio sem nec elit."
end

Factory.define :user do |user|
  user.email "foo@bar.com"
  user.password "foobar"
  user.admin true
end
```

Can someone help me understand?

Comment: What's on posts_controller.rb on line 13 ?

Comment: oh...     @post = Post.new(params[:post].merge!(:user => current_user))

Comment: Maybe, you should pass `Factory.build(:post).attributes` instead of `Factory(:post)` when testing post creation.

Comment: params[:post] should be an array of attrs, but I belive it's the string value of a single input. Check your form structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's telling you what the error is:

```
 undefined method `merge!' for "a-sample-blog-post":String
```

And that's only happening during the `post :create, :post => blog_post` section of your test which means it's directly related to creating a new Post object (and has nothing to do with the `let(:user)` section).

Ruby's [merge](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-merge) method only works on hashes, but the params you are trying to merge the `:user` entry into is a string which is incompatible.

What I'm not seeing is how you're associating users with posts.  For example, you should probably have a `user_id` field in the `Post` model which ties a user to a specific post (to tell you who created that post).

So rewriting this a bit:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  # tell Rails what we should let the user update via a form
  attr_accessible :title, :content

  # == Schema Information
  #
  # Table name: posts
  #
  #  id         :integer         not null, primary key
  #  user_id    :integer
  #  title      :string(255)
  #  content    :text    
  #  created_at :datetime
  #  updated_at :datetime
end
```

In your PostsController

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(params[:post])
  @post.user_id = current_user.id

  if @post.save
    # great success
  else
    # Y U NO SAVE?!
  end
end
```

And your params should include `:title` and `:content`.

If you want to automatically associate your `Factory(:post)` with a user, you can do:

```
Factory.define :post do |post|
  post.association    :user
  post.title          "A sample blog post"
  post.content        "Duis mollis, est non commodo eget lacinia odio sem nec elit."
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 post :create, :post => blog_post
```

is the culprit. Rails 3.1 and higher stop you from passing arbitrary ruby objects as parameters in your tests. You should replace `blog_post` with a hash of attributes (perhaps via factory girl's `attributes_for` method)

Answer (score 0):

Edit /app/controllers/comments_controller.rb

```
#comments_controller.rb   

 def create
     @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
     @comment = @post.comments.create!(comment_params.merge(:user_id => current_user.id))
    redirect_to @post
 end
```